# Sparklyr read database table to distributed DF

Tags: r, apache-spark, amazon-emr, sparkr, sparklyr

Hi I am trying to figure out if there is a way to directly read a DB table to a sparkR dataframe. I have rstudio installed on an EMR cluster which has my hive metastore on it.

I know I can do the following:

```
library(sparklyr)
library(dplyr)
sc <- spark_connect(master = "local")
library(DBI)
query <- "select * from schema.table"
result <- dbGetQuery(sc, query) 
result_t <- copy_to(sc,result)
```

but is there a way to query directly into result_t?

Comment: have you tried `result_t <- tbl(sc, "schema.table")`?

Comment: yeah i did try that and it worked, sorry, forgot to update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like @kevinykuo suggested,

```
result_t <- tbl(sc, "schema.table")
```

Comment: I found result_t <- dbReadTable(sc, "schema.table") as a faster option, but I am new to spark